# Full Count of UL Items - Including Nested ones

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm trying to use jquery to get a count of all `<li>` tags in a list, including the nested ones in a separate `<ul>` but I'm having no luck and I don't see where that has even been answered.  For example, the code below should be 8, but I can't make it work.  Any ideas? It's got to be simple right?

```
    <ul>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li>
  <ul>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  </ul>
</li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a wrapper around your list, you could use `.find()` of `jQuery` to find matching elements. So for your example, if it is wrapped by `div` tag, apply `.find()` on `div` to get all `li` and access the `length` property to get the count. [Read more about `.find()` here](https://api.jquery.com/find/)

```js
console.log($('div').find('li').length);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3
      <ul>
        <li>4</li>
        <li>5</li>
        <li>6</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>7</li>
    <li>8</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Alternatively, if you give the parent `ul` an `id`, you could apply `.find()` on that as well. Something like:

```
<ul id="test">
   ...
</ul>

$('#test').find('li').length;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `document.getElemenstByTagName('LI')` or with jQuery `$('li')` then do `.length` to get the length of the list of `li`'s.

```js
//JavaScript
//var x = document.getElementsByTagName('LI')

//jQuery
var x = $('LI')

console.log(x.length)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li>
  <ul>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  </ul>
</li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a node list with `document.querySelectorAll` and then display the `length`.
Something like this:

```
let liElements = document.querySelectorAll('li');
console.log(liElements.length);
```